# Marginal distribution of Benford's Law

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

This is the last step is calculating the marginal distribution of Benford's law.

$f_X(x) = \sum_{y=0}^9 log(1 + \frac{1}{10x+y}) =\log \Pi_{y=0}^9 (1 + \frac{1}{10x+y}) = log(1+ \frac{1}{x})$

I'm just stuck on the last step can someone please explain why:

$\log \Pi_{y=0}^9 (1 + \frac{1}{10x+y}) = log(1+ \frac{1}{x})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take for example $x=3$. Then

$$\begin{align}
\prod_{y=0}^9 \left(1 + \frac{1}{10x+y}\right) &= \left(1 + \frac{1}{30}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{31}\right) \cdots\left(1 + \frac{1}{39}\right)\\
&=\frac{31}{30} \, \frac{32}{31} \cdots \frac{39}{38} \frac{40}{39}\\
&=\frac{40}{30}\\
&=\frac{4}{3}\\
&=1+\frac{1}{3}
\end{align}
$$

Can you generalize from here?